# Web Map applications increases JAVA heap space memory

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory, geoserver, wms

## The Problem

**Set-up:** We created an application mainly build on the server side. The components are `Postgres/Postgis` (9.4 64bit) and a `Geoserver` (2.8.5) instance. The software is running on an `Ubuntu` 16 64bit OS.

**Intro:** 
The Geoserver publishes raster data coming from the local storage with a size of about 5-10KB as a WMS service and feature data from the Postgis database as WFS service ( max. 30000 feature per layer). On the client side we use leaflet to render the web map. We have a function which retrieves the current BBOX of the map and checks via REST API which layer on the Geoserver fall into this BBOX. The layers appear now and can be toggled on or off.

By doing this **heap space memory** of our tomcat 8 server **increases and reaches almost 100% of workload** which stops the machine more or less. 
The application can be used again, only after the memory of the heap space was cleared either by the Geoserver (under server status in the administration menu) or automatically by the JAVA garbage collector.

## The question

First, why is the **memory used** so much although the raster images are not so large in size?

Second, is there a possibility to **empty the heap space memory** somehow within a JAVA programme or from the command line in case we cannot find out what increases the heap space.

Comment: System.gc(); But you should really figure out why it is (temporarily) using all the memory, because running the garbage collection will lead to pauses, which means your service will not be able to handle/accept requests during this time.

Comment: GeoServer is platform for running a number of plugins.  It sounds like there might be a memory leak in the components connecting to PostGIS or serving the raster data.  

Can you try running your web app with just the vector data and then just the raster data?  If one or the other causes the trouble, that might help identify the issue.

Comment: how much heap memory did you give tomcat's JVM by default it will be too little for GeoServer to survive in. http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html

Comment: @cello @GeoMesaJim @iant Thanks for the replies so far! `System.gc()` is rather dangerous and thus not useable for our system. We gave the tomcat jvm 8gb. That already is more than enough I think. The rasters we serve are stored on the hard disk in the geoserver data dir. 
Only the vector data are stored in the PostGIS table and contain between 1000-25000 features which will be included in the web app as a wfs retrieving the data from the geoserver as geojson!